# SQL One to Many to Many to Many query based on value within table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some basic experience with SQL but am trying to do a query which I am not sure how to approach.

I have the following tables.

```
Member
------
id

Character
--------
Member (References Member)

Activity
---------
id

CharacterActivityStat
--------
activity (references Activity)
character (references Character)
id
fireteamId

WeaponResult
--------
character_activity_stat (references CharacterActivityStat)
```

An Activity has multiple Characters whose results are stored in CharacterActivityStat. Characters who played together, share the same fireteamId. Each CharacterActivityStat may have 0 or more WeaponResults.

I want to pull all WeaponResults linked to all CharacterActivityStats for an Activity, where the fireteamId is not equal to the fireteamid for the CharacterActivityState for the specified Character.

Any suggestions for how to approach this? Even any terms to search on would be helpful.

What I eventually want to do, is do this for multiple activities, and then aggregate the results, but I think if could figure it out for one, it would help get me going in the right direction.

Update: Here is the actual query, which seems to be working now:

```
SELECT
    reference_id as id,
    count(*) as count,
    sum(weapon_result.precision_kills) as precision,
    sum(weapon_result.kills) as kills
    FROM
            weapon_result
    INNER JOIN
    character_activity_stats on weapon_result.character_activity_stats = character_activity_stats.id
    WHERE
        activity in (
          SELECT
            activity.id
          FROM
            character_activity_stats
          INNER JOIN
            activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
            character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
            member on member.id = character.member
          WHERE
            member.id = (select id from member where member_id = @memberId) AND
            (character.class = @characterSelectionId OR 4 = @characterSelectionId) AND
            period > @startDate AND
            period < @endDate AND
            exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @modeId) AND
            not exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @restrictModeId)
        )
    AND
    fireteam_id not in (
        SELECT
            fireteam_id
        FROM
          character_activity_stats
        INNER JOIN
          activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
          character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
          member on member.id = character.member
        WHERE
          member.id = (select id from member where member_id = @memberId)
    ) 
    GROUP BY reference_id
```

ok. This second subquery was returning all rows, and not the rows from the query above. So, I just call the same subquery twice, which is working, but seems inefficient.

```
SELECT
    reference_id as id,
    count(*) as count,
    sum(weapon_result.precision_kills) as precision,
    sum(weapon_result.kills) as kills
    FROM
            weapon_result
    INNER JOIN
    character_activity_stats on weapon_result.character_activity_stats = character_activity_stats.id
    WHERE
        activity in (
          SELECT
            activity.id
          FROM
            character_activity_stats
          INNER JOIN
            activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
            character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
            member on member.id = character.member
          WHERE
            member.id = (select id from member where member_id = @memberId) AND
            (character.class = @characterSelectionId OR 4 = @characterSelectionId) AND
            period > @startDate AND
            period < @endDate AND
            exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @modeId) AND
            not exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @restrictModeId)
        )
    AND
    fireteam_id not in (
    SELECT
    fireteam_id
  FROM
    character_activity_stats
  INNER JOIN
    activity ON character_activity_stats.activity = activity.id,
    character on character_activity_stats.character = character.id,
    member on member.id = character.member
  WHERE
    member.id = (select id from member where member_id = @memberId) AND
    (character.class = @characterSelectionId OR 4 = @characterSelectionId) AND
    period > @startDate AND
    period < @endDate AND
    exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @modeId) AND
    not exists (select 1 from modes where activity = activity.id and mode = @restrictModeId)
    ) 
    GROUP BY reference_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Join statements to get data from different tables.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was doing joins, but was having problems when I am pulling more than one activity. I updated the post with my SQL, but am not sure the second AND (fireteam_id not in) is pulling from all ROWS, or just the subset from above.

Comment: @mikechambers It have it's own subquery so it should be pulling all rows.